# Reverse Proxy with Asp.Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, http-headers, reverse-proxy

I have written a middleware that catches the request and based on the requirement it sends HttpRequest (with the help of HttpClient) and copies all the HTTP response parts(headers, body) from the result to my context. But when I get

> transfer-encoding: chunked

in the header, the response is not returning to the end-user properly.
How can I copy the exact same response to my context and continue correctly?

```
    private void CopyFromTargetResponseHeaders(HttpContext context, HttpResponseMessage responseMessage)
    {
        foreach (var header in responseMessage.Headers)
        {
            context.Response.Headers[header.Key] = header.Value.ToArray();
        }

        foreach (var header in responseMessage.Content.Headers)
        {
           context.Response.Headers[header.Key] = header.Value.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Per my searching, when using `transfer-encoding: chunked` but not `Content-Length` in the request header, that always means the length of the content is unpredictable, and it will be divided into several parts then send one by one. Therefore I just wanna check if the requests received by your middleware is complete when request header has "transfer-encoding"?

Comment: The request is getting completed but because of response header's it copies transfer-encoding: chunked as well.